# Hashing a struct

Tags: solidity, struct, hash

I'd like to digest a data structure (a struct) with keccak256, but solc (0.4.23) tells me "Error: This type cannot be encoded."

Is there a good reason why can't solidity encode the struct? That looks like a straightforward job to me.

My current workaround is to manually call abi.encodePacked with each individual element of the structure, plus (as a header) a constant that lets me distinguish easily between different data structures. It's syntactically more cumbersome, and is not as type-safe as if I could hash the struct directly, but it does the job. Is that the right thing to do?

Comment: The function `abi.encodedPacked` is new since 0.4.22. My guess is that it was a change required for hashing structs and in the future they will add support for it using encodePacked.